# Qt subwidget automatic resizing in QHBoxLayout

Tags: qt, widget, pyqt

I have a QTableView.  When the table grows, the table view adds scrollbars, even when it could just expand to take more room in the QHBoxLayout.  How do I make it expand?

Comment: I suggest it won't expand depending on its contents. You may make it initially expanded to maximum size, or implement custom function which will resize it for example on row adding, but as far I know there is no native mechanism for that action.